# Remainder operator of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

> Here I'm considering the $\Bbb{R}$-vector space $E$ of all polynomials with degree $n\in\Bbb{Z}_+$ or less and $f\colon E\to E$ the operator that maps $P\in E$ to the remainder of the euclidian division of $XP$ for $A(X)=X^{n+1}+\sum_{k=0}^na_kX^k$. I need to find the matrix of $f$ in the basis $\{1,X,...,X^n\}$.

I already proved that $f$ is linear, and if $P(X)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}b_kX^k$ then $$f(P)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(b_{k-1}-a_kb_n)X^k\right)-a_0b_n.$$ But now, I don't know how to procede in compute of $f(1)$, $f(X)$, etc...

Comment: Well, $X^i$ has coefficients $(0,\dots,0,\underbrace{\ 1\ }_{i\text{th place}},0\dots)$

Comment: Well $f(1)=$ remainder of $X.1$, so is just $X$. And then $f(X)=X^2$, and so on, until $f(X^n)=$ remainder when we divide $X^{n+1}$ by $A(X)$, so is  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B = \{1,X,...,X^n\}$ be the canonical basis of $E$. Since $f$ associates a polynomial $P$ to the rest of the division of $PX$ by $A$, we have that, for every $j = 1,...,n-1$, $$f(X^j) = X^{j+1}$$ since the degree of $X^{j+1}$ is strictly smaller than the degree of $A$. However, $$f(X^n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}-a_KX^k,$$ because $X^{n+1} = 1 \cdot A - \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kX^k .$ With these information, we can compute the matrix of $f$ in the basis $B$:
$$\left [f \right ]_B =  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & -a_1 \\ 
1 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & -a_2\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & \vdots & -a_3\\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 & 0 & -a_{n-1} \\ 
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1 & -a_n 
\end{bmatrix}.$$